# Set a max width in an align full or align wide block on Gutenberg

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, wordpress-gutenberg

The width of the 'aligfull' and 'alighwide' gutenberg block in bigger screens is getting the inside content out of the permitted max width (1200px) content margins on my site, see image attached. 
I have not found a good solution to set limits to this, if I add a max-width, then the background is also limited to that max width (I don't want this, I want to be able to add full width colors or image bg), and adding the negative margins to extend the area also breaks the layout.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you use bootstrap or other libraries? Put your related code here. Html, css and js

Comment: In this case, I do not use bootstrap. is just gutenberg and my theme @SiamakFerdos you can see the actual page here: https://grownuptravel.feedmybeta.com/why-book-with-us/